Google Analytics with ReactGA4 how to add e-commerce events?
I cannot figure out the data format used with the ReactGA4 package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4
Google suggest to add many important parameters such as currency, items and prices:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag#add_or_remove_an_item_from_a_shopping_cart
ReactGA4.event({ category: "add_to_cart", action: "Add To Cart", currency: "USD", amount: "10", items: [] });

Though the events don't appear on Analytics and I don't think the format is correct since it doesn't show on the debugger.
The npm package was not really written using typescript so it's impossible to find out from the source code what format I should use.
